# MongoDB - Getting first set of $lt

Tags: mongodb, date

I'm using MongoDB to store data and when retrieving some, I need a subset which I'm uncertain how to obtain.

The situation is this; items are created in batches, spanning about a month between. When a new batch is added, the previous batch has a `deleted_on` date set.

Now, depending on when a customer is created, they can always retrieve the current (not deleted) set of items, and all items in the one batch that wasn't deleted when they registered.

Thus, I want to retrieve records that have `deleted_on` as either `null`, or **all items** that have the `deleted_on` on the closest date in the future from the `customer.added_on`-date.

In all of my solutions, I run into one of the below problems:

- I can get all items that were deleted before the customer was created - but they include all batches - not just the latest one.
- I can get the first item that was deleted after the customer was created, but nothing else from the same batch.
- I can get all items, but I have to modify the result set afterwards to remove all items that don't apply.

Having to modify the result afterwards is fine, I guess, but undesirable. What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

PS. The `added_on` (on the customer) and `deleted_on` on the items have indexes.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some example documents? Doesn't have to be real data - just so we can understand what the schema is. And what queries are you currently trying?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, tfogo =) I'll make sure to add some examples first thing tomorrow when I get to the office! =)